# Styling is different between pages HTML CSS JS with similar code

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, text

I am building a website and I cannot tell a difference between two HTML/CSS/JS files to see what is making my logo, button, and the main text a different style. The first code is the desired look for the website's logo, button, and main text but the second is incorrect. Any help will be appriciated!
My desired HTML style for the logo, buttons, and main text styling is on this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <section class="showcase">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   window.addEventListener('load', () => {
       const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
       const showcase = document.querySelector('.showcase');

       menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
           menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
           showcase.classList.toggle('active');
       })
   });
      </script>
  <header>
     <style>
         @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
*
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 40px 100px;
 z-index: 1000;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}
header .logo
{
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle
{
 position: relative;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/HrfVRcx/menu.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 30px;
 background-position: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle.active
{
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/rt3HybH/close.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 25px;
 background-position: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.showcase
{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 padding: 100px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 background: #011721;
 transition: 0.5s;
 z-index: 2;
}
.showcase.active
{
 right: 300px;
}

.showcase video
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.text
{
 z-index: 10;
}

.text h2
{
 font-size: 5em;
 font-weight: 800;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.menu ul
{
 position: relative;
}
.menu ul li
{
 list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #011721;
}
.menu ul li a:hover
{
 color: #03a9f4; 
}

@media (max-width: 991px)
{
 .showcase,
 .showcase header
 {
   padding: 40px;
 }
 .text h2
 {
   font-size: 3em;
 }
}
     </style>
     <h2 class="logo">Sample Logo</h2>
     <div class="toggle"></div>
   </header>
   <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">
    <p id='text'>You Can Contact Us Here</p>
    <a href="tel:"><button id='back'>Call</button></a>
    <a href="mailto:><button id='email'>Email</button></a>
   </div>
   </div>
 </section>
 <div class="menu">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
    <style>
        #text {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-size: 3em;
            font-weight: 800;
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 2em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 3em;
            margin: 20px 0;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align:center;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 45%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #back
        {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        background: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #111;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        transition: 0.2s;
        justify-content: center;
        border: none;
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 80%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #back:hover
        {
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        }
        #email
        {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        background: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #111;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        transition: 0.2s;
        justify-content: center;
        border: none;
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 90%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #email:hover
        {
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The different styling on the second page for the buttons/logo/main text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <section class="showcase">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   window.addEventListener('load', () => {
       const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
       const showcase = document.querySelector('.showcase');

       menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
           menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
           showcase.classList.toggle('active');
       })
   });
      </script>
  <header>
     <style>
#form {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-size: 5em;
            font-weight: 800;
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 2em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 5em;
            margin: 20px 0;
            max-width: 700px;
        }
  #logintext {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-size: 5em;
            font-weight: 800;
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 1em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 7em;
            margin: 20px 0;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align:center;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 20%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
  #formGroupExampleInput {
    width: 75%;
    height: 3%;
    background-color:#fff;
    border: none;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 52.5%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  #formGroupExampleInput2 {
    width: 75%;
    height: 3%;
    background-color:#fff;
    border: none;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 75%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #usernamelabel {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #passwordlabel {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 65%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #submit
        {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 1em;
        background: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #111;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        transition: 0.2s;
        justify-content: center;
        position: absolute;
        border: none;
        left: 50%;
        top: 87.5%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
  #submit:hover
        {
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        }

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header .logo {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/HrfVRcx/menu.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle.active {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/rt3HybH/close.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.showcase {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #011721;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.showcase.active {
  right: 300px;
}

.showcase video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.text {
  z-index: 10;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu ul {
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #011721;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #03a9f4;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .showcase,
  .showcase header {
    padding: 40px;
  }
}
     </style>
     <h2 class="logo">Sample Logo</h2>
     <div class="toggle"></div>
   </header>
   <h2 id='logintext'>Login</h2>
   <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">
    <form id='form' action="/login" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id='usernamelabel' for="formGroupExampleInput">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput"  name="username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id='passwordlabel' for="formGroupExampleInput2">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2"  name="password">
      </div>
      <button id='submit' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </form>
   </div>
   </div>
 </section>
 <div class="menu">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
<html>
    <style>
        #text {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-size: 3em;
            font-weight: 800;
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 2em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 3em;
            margin: 20px 0;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align:center;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 45%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #back
        {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        background: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #111;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        transition: 0.2s;
        justify-content: center;
        border: none;
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 80%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #back:hover
        {
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        }
        #email
        {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        background: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #111;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        transition: 0.2s;
        justify-content: center;
        border: none;
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 90%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #email:hover
        {
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is in the flow of your page and your whole mark-up/ordering. All page contents should go in the `<body></body>` of your HTML page. All styling should be in the `<head></head>` of your page, before the content. I'd suggest you brush up your knowledge on HTML Basics; https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are missing a open html tag and also missing a closing quote mailto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
 <section class="showcase">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   window.addEventListener('load', () => {
       const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
       const showcase = document.querySelector('.showcase');

       menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
           menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
           showcase.classList.toggle('active');
       })
   });
      </script>
  <header>
     <style>
         @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
*
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 40px 100px;
 z-index: 1000;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
}
header .logo
{
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle
{
 position: relative;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/HrfVRcx/menu.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 30px;
 background-position: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle.active
{
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/rt3HybH/close.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 25px;
 background-position: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.showcase
{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 padding: 100px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 background: #011721;
 transition: 0.5s;
 z-index: 2;
}
.showcase.active
{
 right: 300px;
}

.showcase video
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
.text
{
 z-index: 10;
}

.text h2
{
 font-size: 5em;
 font-weight: 800;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.menu ul
{
 position: relative;
}
.menu ul li
{
 list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #011721;
}
.menu ul li a:hover
{
 color: #03a9f4; 
}

@media (max-width: 991px)
{
 .showcase,
 .showcase header
 {
   padding: 40px;
 }
 .text h2
 {
   font-size: 3em;
 }
}
     </style>
     <h2 class="logo">Sample Logo</h2>
     <div class="toggle"></div>
   </header>
   <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">
    <p id='text'>You Can Contact Us Here</p>
    <a href="tel:"><button id='back'>Call</button></a>
    <a href="mailto:"><button id='email'>Email</button></a>
   </div>
   </div>
 </section>
 <div class="menu">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
    <style>
        #text {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            font-size: 3em;
            font-weight: 800;
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 2em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 3em;
            margin: 20px 0;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align:center;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 45%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #back
        {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        background: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #111;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        transition: 0.2s;
        justify-content: center;
        border: none;
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 80%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #back:hover
        {
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        }
        #email
        {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        background: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #111;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        transition: 0.2s;
        justify-content: center;
        border: none;
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 90%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        #email:hover
        {
        letter-spacing: 6px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <section class="showcase">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   window.addEventListener('load', () => {
   const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
   const showcase = document.querySelector('.showcase');

   menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
       menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
       showcase.classList.toggle('active');
   })
   });
  </script>
  <header>
 <style>
#form {
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 5em;
        font-weight: 800;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 2em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 5em;
        margin: 20px 0;
        max-width: 700px;
    }
  #logintext {
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 5em;
        font-weight: 800;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 1em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 7em;
        margin: 20px 0;
        max-width: 700px;
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 20%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  #formGroupExampleInput {
width: 75%;
height: 3%;
background-color:#fff;
border: none;
text-align:center;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 52.5%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  #formGroupExampleInput2 {
width: 75%;
height: 3%;
background-color:#fff;
border: none;
text-align:center;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 75%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #usernamelabel {
text-align:center;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 40%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #passwordlabel {
text-align:center;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 65%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #submit
    {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #111;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    left: 50%;
    top: 87.5%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  #submit:hover
    {
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    }

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header .logo {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/HrfVRcx/menu.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle.active {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/rt3HybH/close.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.showcase {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #011721;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.showcase.active {
  right: 300px;
}

.showcase video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.text {
  z-index: 10;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu ul {
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #011721;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #03a9f4;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .showcase,
  .showcase header {
padding: 40px;
  }
}
 </style>
 <h2 class="logo">Sample Logo</h2>
 <div class="toggle"></div>
   </header>
   <h2 id='logintext'>Login</h2>
   <div class="overlay">
   <div class="text">
<form id='form' action="/login" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label id='usernamelabel' for="formGroupExampleInput">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput"  name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label id='passwordlabel' for="formGroupExampleInput2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2"  name="password">
  </div>
  <button id='submit' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>
   </div>
   </div>
 </section>
 <div class="menu">
   <ul>
 <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
 <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
<html>
<style>
    #text {
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size: 3em;
        font-weight: 800;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 2em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 3em;
        margin: 20px 0;
        max-width: 700px;
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 45%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    #back
    {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    background: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #111;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    justify-content: center;
    border: none;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    #back:hover
    {
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    }
    #email
    {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    background: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #111;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    justify-content: center;
    border: none;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 90%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    #email:hover
    {
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    }
</style>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I was looking to change the styling on the second page so it looks like the first page. Can I accomplish this?